# Implement transactions and concurrent access in EF 6.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, concurrency, transactions

I have a working WPF application that uses EF 6.0 to connect to MS SQL Server database. I am moving this application from standalone to a network where different users will have different permissions on the application. Some will only be able to generate reports (Read only access), some will be able to edit/update/delete data and some will be able to import data from excel files (huge amount of data in excel files). So I believe I need to manage transactions in my application so that multiple users when access the same data, then there is no concurrency issues. How do I manage the transactions and concurrency here?

P.S: I have a Roles & Users table in the database. There are some predefined Roles and each user has a certain roles based on which user has controlled access to the application workflows.

Comment: Is your application handling authentication and authorization (a table or 3 for credentials) or are these deferred to the database (each user has an individual login to the database)?

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent requests, where two different users try to update the same piece of data (i.e. a row in a database table). I could go on for a bit, but I found a [decent article on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

The short version is that you need to have a rowversion column on the tables. This is a column that the database automatically increments with each update.

You need to identify the column as a Timestamp column either with an attribute in code first, or in the edmx file. (rowversion used to be called a timestamp)

This will cause SaveChanges calls to throw a [DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx) when a concurrency conflict happens.

You can catch that and react how you need to.